# How to do the 'curvy L' for Lagrangian or Laplace Transforms?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

I am new to TeX, working on it for about 2 months. Have not yet figured out how to script the 'curvy L' for Lagrangian and/or for Laplace Transforms.

As of now I am using the 'L' - which is not good! :-(

Any help?

**UPDATE** The 2 best solutions are;

```
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\mathcal{L}
```

and

```
\usepackage{ mathrsfs }
\mathscr{L}
```

I got my answers at, http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: if using Scientific word, click on this panel ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uQrMT.png)  and if using Lyx, click on this panel ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PRTOk.png)

Comment: Relates: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239791/is-this-laplace-transform-symbol-available-in-latex

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You have been told how to get a curved L. But here's some more general advice, which also applies in this situation: In cases such as this, *always* create your own shortcut macro, say

```
\newcommand{\Lagr}{\mathcal{L}}
```

This way, if you ever decide that that curly L is not quite the one you like, it is easy to switch. Also, even before you knew the answer to this question, you could have written

```
\newcommand{\Lagr}{L}
```

in your preamble. Then you could start/continue writing the document, use ordinary capital Ls where you want, and `\Lagr` wherever you actually mean a Lagrangian, and then later changing the definition of `\Lagr` to something appropriate. This way, you wouldn't have to manually search for each occurence of a capital L and decide if it's a Lagrangian or not. Clearly `\Lagr` (or whatever you want to call this macro) is also easier to type than `\mathcal{L}`, and it makes the source code much more readable.

Another advantage, which is probably more subtle, since you're new to LaTeX, is that we can make the curvy L exactly the type of math we want. TeX distinguishes between ordinary letters, binary operators, binary relations, opening and closing parenthesis and so on; the spacing between two ordinary letters is not the same as the spacing between the `a`, `+`, and `b` in `$a+b$`. So since the Lagrangian is a kind of operator, we could say

```
\newcommand{\Lagr}{\mathop{\mathcal{L}}}
```

But in the case of operators, the package amsmath (which you are most likely using; if not, you should) provides a somewhat better mechanism:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Lagr}{\mathcal{L}}
```

*Added:* Another (related) tip: Even if you are using the same notation for two different things, it is best to make a separate macro for each. In this case you might have

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Lagr}{\mathcal{L}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Lapl}{\mathcal{L}}
```

The reason is the same as in the `L` vs. `\Lagr` case above: If you at some point decide that using `\mathcal{L}` for both is a bad idea, you would have to find each occurence of `\Lagr` and figure out if it is really a Laplacian. Using macro names carrying semantic meaning is one of the great powers of TeX.

Answer (score 64):

```
$\mathcal{L}$
```

---

It renders as...

[image: screen capture of mathematics calligraphy "L" as in "Larry"]

---

Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use the `mathrsfs` package (put `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` in your preamble), and its command `\mathscr` (e.g. `$\mathscr{L}$` should give you what you want) to get more script-like, curvy letters.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned:

```latex
$\mathcal{L}$
```

Per the Calligraphic section in this (excellent) [Latex cheatsheet](http://tug.ctan.org/info/undergradmath/undergradmath.pdf).

[image: A section from the cheatsheet showing calligraphic letter]

Answer (score 2):

Also note that you can select from many different `\mathcal` alphabets in LaTeX, if you don’t like the default ℒ.

In `unicode-math`, you can change the `\mathcal` alphabet with `\setmathfont[range={cal,bfcal}]{Some font}`.  Here are some [specimens of several fonts.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf)

In PDFTeX, the most robust way to change these math alphabets is `mathalpha` with the `[cal=...]` option.  [The documentation has font specimens of every available calligraphic alphabet](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf).