# Curvy L with amssymb package

Tags: fonts, amssymb

I want to display a **curvy L n°1**:

[image: curvy L n°1]

(An application is found [here](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) as well as [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11031/how-to-do-the-curvy-l-for-lagrangian-or-laplace-transforms).)

However, when I enter the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}

$\mathcal{L}$

\end{document}
```

I get **curvy L n°2**:

[image: Curvy L n°2]

How can I print the **curvy L n°1**?

Comment: comment `\usepackage{mathptmx}` line and try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you adding the two rows

```
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
```

it is possibile, in the same file `.tex`, to use the both curvy option. I have removed `\usepackage{amsmath}` with `\usepackage{mathtools}` because loading `mathtools`, you will have both packages loaded and you do not need to `\usepackage{amsmath}` in your preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{calrsfs}%%%%%%%%%%<------add
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}%%%%%%%%%%<------add

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}

$\mathcal{L}, \pazocal{L}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Comment `\usepackage{mathptmx}`.

Read page 5 in documentation of [mathptmx](http://mirror.iopb.res.in/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf). It says that the fonts for `\mathcal` symbols will be changed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}

$\mathcal{L}$

\end{document}
```

[image]